# Completion of paramitas

Tags: pali-canon, sutta-reference

Is it possible to complete all paramitas without physically doing anything?

If so, then how & where is it mentioned in tipitaka?

In previous birth, while bowing down to dipankara, Gautama thought that if he wants he can destroy all dukkha just now and liberate.. how?

Or these paramitas are for someone aspiring to be self enlightened only? If yes then sutta-refence.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but some pointers in the right direction and a nitpick about terminology: paramitas (skt) are generally a Mahayana thing, not Theravada, though they are mentioned (pāramīs in Pali) in a few places in KN: the Buddhavaṃsa 1 and 2, Apadāna, and Cariyāpiṭaka 1 ([a link with some references](https://suttacentral.net/search?query=p%C4%81ram%C4%AB)).

Answer (score 1):

No, paramitas cannot be achieved without physically doing anything. As one example, paramita of morality- silaparamita- requires perfection of sila- sila is performed at three levels- body, speech and mind. The sila of body requires includes physical acts. There are other ways to demonstrate that without doing anything physically, paramitas cannot be accomplished.